# How to inherit selfs from parent MainWindow class in pyqt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

My `Ui_MainWindow` class looks like this:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(271, 429)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.lbl_adres = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.lbl_adres.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 20, 47, 13))
        self.lbl_adres.setObjectName("lbl_adres")
...
```

I created new `Connection` class below outside the parent class and want to get access to `lbl_adres`:

```
class Connection(Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()

        #I Want to access parent class element here
        print(self.lbl_adres.text())
...
```

However, this inheritance doest work at all and i get following error:

`AttributeError: 'Connection' object has no attribute 'lbl_adres'`

I understand, Connection class cannot refer to UI_MainWindow items becouse i write it wrong. I just want to change something in future in parent class like text from Connection class. How to resolve this?

Comment: See: [Using Qt Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) in the PyQt docs. The third example there is what you want.

Comment: thank you very much, i am using pyside6 and the example in pyside docs wasn't proper, this example is what i needed

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want inheritance here ? (nb: inheritance means a "is a" relationship, not "has a" relationship). Given you question's title it seems you don't really grasp OO yet (hint: "inherits self from parent classes" doesn't make any sense - `self` is the object on which the method has been invoked).

If yes, then your issue comes from trying to access an attribute that is not *yet* created - it's `Ui_MainWindow.setupUI()` which creates this attribute, so it's doesn't exist before you call this method.

Else, please explain more clearly what you're really trying to do (I mean: explain the problem, not what you think the solution is).